# Welch-Satterthwaite equation for effective degrees of freedom

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, measurement

Using Welch-Satterthwaite equation to calculate the effective degrees of freedom i got 0.29, is that possible? What is the meaning of that equation and how can i know if I messed up somewhere?

Comment: Can you provide information about the context in which you obtained this value of $\nu ?$

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a Welch 2-sample t test, with sample
sizes $n_1$ and $n_2,$ then the Satterthwaite DF $\nu$ must
have

$$\min(n_1-1, n_2-1) \le \nu \le n_1+n_2 - 2.$$

So, in that context $\nu = 0.29$ would not be possible; the Welch test is not valid for samples of size one.
However, there is nothing wrong with non-integer DF in a t distribution. [See end notes and [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) on Student's t distribution.]

The smaller bound can be approached in case the two
sample variances are extremely different, as in the
example below, where $\nu = 4.0012 \approx n_1 -1 = 4.$
The larger bound is approached if $S_1^2 \approx S_2^2.$

```
set.seed(2022)
x1 = rnorm(5, 100, 25)
x2 = rnorm(50, 100, 1)
t.test(x1, x2)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  x1 and x2
t = -1.4199, df = 4.0012, p-value = 0.2286
alternative hypothesis: 
 true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -43.58782  14.08874
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 85.26898 100.01852 

var(x1); var(x2)
[1] 539.4698
[1] 0.7861283
```

*Notes:* (1) R will accept a sample of size $1$ in
the pooled version of `t.test` (parameter `var.eq=T`), but not in the Welch version.

```
t.test(5, x2, var.eq=T)$p.val
[1] 1.434898e-59

t.test(5, x2)
Error in t.test.default(5, x2) : 
  not enough 'x' observations
```

(2) Output for Welch 2-sample t tests in some statistical software
programs rounds $\nu$ to integer values; R shows fractional
degrees of freedom.

(3) Student's t distribution can be defined
for fractional DF. In R:

```
qt(.975, 30.5)
[1] 2.040869
qt(.975, 30)
[1] 2.042272
qt(.975, 31)
[1] 2.039513
```